# List all soft deleted users from Azure AD directory

Tags: azure-active-directory

Command let provided by MS has a rate limit.

```html
Get-MgDirectoryDeletedItem -DirectoryObjectId microsoft.graph.user -Property '*'
```

Above Mg Graph command let returning only 100(max) values. However, i have around 1000 values in the deleted list. Also, it do not take "-All", "Page Size" etc properties.

Any guidance on how can i get the list all deleted users via PowerShell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Mg Graph command let returning only 100(max) values. However, i have around 1000 values in the deleted list. Also, it do not take "-All", "Page Size" etc properties.

Here is the command to get more than 100 `Azure AD` deleted users.

**Powershell Comamnd:**

```
Install-Module Microsoft.Graph.Identity.DirectoryManagement
Get-MgDirectoryDeletedItemAsUser -PageSize 114 | Export-Csv -Path "C:\ZipFolder\AzureADuserdel-27-2023.csv"
```

**MS Graph Result:**

[image]

> Note:  PageSize 114 define the number as per your requirement.

[image]

Once the above command is run, it will fetch deleted `Azure AD` users and export them to an excel file as below.

**Output:**

[image]

Reference:  [Retrieve the count of deleted user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directory-deleteditems-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-2-retrieve-the-count-of-deleted-user-objects-and-order-the-results-by-the-deleteddatetime-property)

Comment: Thanks Venket - I knew to use MSOL command for this but i also want run it as a daily task and i did not find any way to use access token or certificate with it. Do not want to use user creds for this. Do you know any way to use access token or cert with it or that is just with MS Graph?